# I want to display the Video on the Pyqt MainWindow. The code processing but not Displaying in the window

Tags: pyqt5

> Thi code is PyQT5 program according to the details the main window should display the video but it is failing to do so. The below code will include the run function. How can it be improved?

```
class ActionRecognitionGUI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ActionRecognitionGUI, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Human Action Recognition")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)

        self.source = ''
        self.detection_input_size = 640
        self.pose_input_size = '256x192'
        self.pose_backbone = 'resnet50'
        self.show_detected = True
        self.show_skeleton = False
        self.save_out = ''
        self.device = 'cuda'

        self.graphics_view = QGraphicsView(self)
        self.graphics_scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.graphics_view.setScene(self.graphics_scene)

        self.load_button = QPushButton("Load Video", self)
        self.load_button.clicked.connect(self.load_video)

        self.start_button = QPushButton("Start Recognition", self)
        self.start_button.clicked.connect(self.start_recognition)

        self.stop_button = QPushButton("Stop", self)
        self.stop_button.clicked.connect(self.stop_recognition)
        self.stop_button.setEnabled(False)

        self.detection_input_size_label = QLabel("Detection Input Size:", self)
        self.detection_input_size_edit = QLineEdit(str(self.detection_input_size), self)
        self.detection_input_size_edit.setMaximumWidth(100)

        self.device_label = QLabel("Device:", self)
        self.device_combo = QComboBox(self)
        self.device_combo.addItem("cuda")
        self.device_combo.setCurrentIndex(0)  # Set CUDA as default

        self.show_skeleton_checkbox = QCheckBox("Show Skeleton", self)
        self.show_skeleton_checkbox.setChecked(self.show_skeleton)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.graphics_view)

        options_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        options_layout.addWidget(self.load_button)
        options_layout.addWidget(self.start_button)
        options_layout.addWidget(self.stop_button)
        options_layout.addWidget(self.detection_input_size_label)
        options_layout.addWidget(self.detection_input_size_edit)
        options_layout.addWidget(self.device_label)
        options_layout.addWidget(self.device_combo)
        options_layout.addWidget(self.show_skeleton_checkbox)

        layout.addLayout(options_layout)

        central_widget = QWidget(self)
        central_widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_frame)
        self.is_recognizing = False

        self.action_recognition = HumanActionRecognition(self.source, self.detection_input_size, self.pose_input_size,
                                                         self.pose_backbone, self.show_detected, self.show_skeleton,
                                                         self.save_out, self.device)

    def load_video(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        filename, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Load Video", "", "Video Files (*.mp4 *.avi *.mkv)", options=options)
        if filename:
            self.source = filename

    def start_recognition(self):
        if not self.is_recognizing:
            self.is_recognizing = True
            self.detection_input_size = int(self.detection_input_size_edit.text())
            self.device = self.device_combo.currentText().lower()
            self.show_skeleton = self.show_skeleton_checkbox.isChecked()

            self.action_recognition.source = self.source
            self.action_recognition.detection_input_size = self.detection_input_size
            self.action_recognition.show_skeleton = self.show_skeleton
            self.action_recognition.device = self.device

            self.timer.start(1)
            self.start_button.setEnabled(False)
            self.stop_button.setEnabled(True)

    def stop_recognition(self):
        if self.is_recognizing:
            self.is_recognizing = False
            self.action_recognition.cam.stop()
            self.timer.stop()
            self.start_button.setEnabled(True)
            self.stop_button.setEnabled(False)

    def update_frame(self):
        frame = self.action_recognition.run()
        frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        # Convert the frame to QImage
        height, width, channel = frame.shape
        bytes_per_line = 3 * width
        q_image = QImage(frame.data, width, height, bytes_per_line, QImage.Format_BGR888)

        # Check for errors in QImage construction
        if q_image.isNull():
            print("Error: Failed to create QImage")
            return

        # Create a QPixmap from the QImage
        pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(q_image)

        # Check if QPixmap creation failed
        if pixmap.isNull():
            print("Error: Failed to create QPixmap")
            return

        # Clear the graphics scene and add the pixmap
        self.graphics_scene.clear()
        self.graphics_scene.addPixmap(pixmap)

        # Adjust the view to fit the scene
        self.graphics_view.fitInView(self.graphics_scene.sceneRect())
```

```
    def run(self):
        par = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Human Fall Detection Demo.')
        par.add_argument('-C', '--camera', default=self.source,
                          help='Source of camera or video file path.')
        par.add_argument('--device', type=str, default=self.device,
                          help='Device to run model on cpu or cuda.')
        args = par.parse_args()

        device = args.device

        # DETECTION MODEL.
        inp_dets = self.detection_input_size

        # POSE MODEL.
        inp_pose = self.pose_input_size.split('x')
        inp_pose = (int(inp_pose[0]), int(inp_pose[1]))
        pose_model = SPPE_FastPose(self.pose_backbone, inp_pose[0], inp_pose[1], device=device)

        # Tracker.
        max_age = 5
        tracker = Tracker(max_age=max_age, n_init=3)

        action_model = TSSTG()

        cam_source = args.camera
        if type(cam_source) is str and os.path.isfile(cam_source):
            self.cam = CamLoader_Q(cam_source, queue_size=10000, preprocess=self.preproc).start()
        else:
            self.cam = CamLoader(int(cam_source) if cam_source.isdigit() else cam_source,
                                 preprocess=self.preproc).start()

        outvid = False
        if self.save_out != '':
            outvid = True
            codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
            self.writer = cv2.VideoWriter(self.save_out, codec, 30, (inp_dets, inp_dets))

        fps_time = 0
        f = 0
        while self.cam.grabbed():
            f += 1
            frame = self.cam.getitem()
            image = frame.copy()
            results = self.model.predict(frame, classes=[0])
            for result in results:
                if len(result.boxes.xyxy) == 0:
                    detected = None
                else:
                    detected = result.boxes.xyxy.cpu()
                    boxes = result.boxes.conf.cpu()

            tracker.predict()

            for track in tracker.tracks:
                det = torch.tensor([track.to_tlbr().tolist()], dtype=torch.float32)
                if detected is not None:
                    detected_xywh = torch.zeros_like(detected)
                    detected_xywh[:, 0] = (detected[:, 0] + detected[:, 2]) / 2
                    detected_xywh[:, 1] = (detected[:, 1] + detected[:, 3]) / 2
                    detected_xywh[:, 2] = detected[:, 2] - detected[:, 0]
                    detected_xywh[:, 3] = detected[:, 3] - detected[:, 1]
                else:
                    detected = det

            detections = []
            if detected is not None:
                poses = pose_model.predict(frame, detected, boxes)
                detections = [Detection(self.kpt2bbox(ps['keypoints'].numpy()),
                                        np.concatenate((ps['keypoints'].numpy(),
                                                        ps['kp_score'].numpy()), axis=1),
                                        ps['kp_score'].mean().numpy()) for ps in poses]

            tracker.update(detections)

            for i, track in enumerate(tracker.tracks):
                if not track.is_confirmed():
                    continue

                track_id = track.track_id
                bbox = track.to_tlbr().astype(int)
                center = track.get_center().astype(int)

                action = 'predicting..'
                clr = (255, 0, 0)
                if len(track.keypoints_list) == 30:
                    pts = np.array(track.keypoints_list, dtype=np.float32)
                    out = action_model.predict(pts, frame.shape[:2])
                    action_name = action_model.class_names[out[0].argmax()]
                    action = '{}'.format(action_name)
                    if action_name == 'Fall Down':
                        clr = (255, 0, 0)
                    elif action_name == 'Lying Down':
                        clr = (255, 200, 0)

                if track.time_since_update == 0:
                    if self.show_skeleton:
                        frame = draw_single(frame, track.keypoints_list[-1])
                    frame = cv2.putText(frame, str(track_id), (center[0], center[1]), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,
                                        1.5, (255, 0, 0), 4)
                    frame = cv2.putText(frame, action, (bbox[0] - 5, bbox[1] - 15), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.8,
                                        clr, 2)

            frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0, 0), fx=1., fy=1.)
            frame = cv2.putText(frame, '%d, FPS: %f' % (f, 1.0 / (time.time() - fps_time)),
                                (10, 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0), 1)
            frame = frame[:, :, ::-1]
            fps_time = time.time()
```

I want to display the Video on the Pyqt MainWindow. The code processing but not Displaying in the window. Unfortunately it showing blank window but the detection is still running.